# How to rename all folders?

Tags: python, rename, python-2.5

I have the code like below:

```
temp = os.walk(sys.argv[1])
for root, dirs, files in temp:
    for i in dirs:
        dir = os.path.join(root,i)
        os.rename(dir, dir+"!")
```

It works almost ok. But once parent folder is renamed, it can not rename subfolders. How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Walk the tree with `topdown` set to False instead:

```
temp = os.walk(sys.argv[1], topdown=False)
for root, dirs, files in temp:
    for i in dirs:
        dir = os.path.join(root,i)
        os.rename(dir, dir+"!")
```

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk):

> If optional argument *topdown* is `True` or not specified, the triple for a directory is generated before the triples for any of its subdirectories (directories are generated top-down). If *topdown* is `False`, the triple for a directory is generated after the triples for all of its subdirectories (directories are generated bottom-up).

Thus, you get to rename sub-directories first, and will see the top-level directories last, and renaming them will no longer affect how the sub-directories are found.

Comment: @LA_ I have an incident question: are path and directory the same thing in Python ? I tried your piece of code with a directory name instead of `sys.argv[0]` like that `temp = os.walk('F:\\WORK\\ALGOCODE')` and `dirs` list is empty. I am ok from doc with Martijn explanation.